# Azure DevOps Task ScriptArguments # comment issue in ScriptArguments

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

These are from YAML

```
task: "AzurePowerShell@4" 
ScriptArguments: '-parametername $(variable)'
```

Another task

```
task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
overrideParameters: '-parametername $(variable)'
```

If the variable value is `'#wert'` then the `ScriptArguments` gives error. because it is evaluating '#' as comment. but `Overrideparameter` in the other task is not(so the second task succeeds).

1. Why is this difference in behavior between overrideParameters & ScriptArguments ?
2. How can we prevent this?

This happened to me as the password brought in by the keyvault had hash in it. This is difficult to test for me as many a times autogenerated passwords may not have #.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why is this difference in behavior between overrideParameters &
   ScriptArguments ?

Because one uses powershell(ScriptArguments) and other does not

1. How can we prevent this?

> ScriptArguments: '-parametername `"$(variable)"`'